# Swift protocol delegate unexpectedly found nil in UIViewController

Tags: swift3, swift-protocols

I have declared a protocol in one view controller and want to call a function in it's presenting view controller. I am not using storyboards.

This `delegate!.setWishListButton()` causes an error `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional`. I know I shouldn't use ! but it's for testing since my delegate function is never called.

I know there are many questions about this but none that matches my usage. I have a similar pattern in a UIView which works fine.

Here is my code

```
protocol SetWishListButtonDelegate {
  func setWishListButton()
}

class MyViewController: UIViewController {

var delegate : SetWishListButtonDelegate?

------

    func toggleWishListButton() {

    delegate?.setWishListButton()
}
```

In another view controller

```
class anotherViewController: UIViewController, SetWishListButtonDelegate {

let myViewController = MyViewController()

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    myViewController.delegate = self
 }

func setWishListButton() {

    print("DELEGATE METHOD FIRED")

    wishListButton.isSelected = true
 }
```

Comment: Where is `someFunction` being called?

Comment: Question edited. the calling function calls an API then the delegate.

Answer (score 0):

This worked after I removed a second declaration of my view controller in a function where it was presented by a button press.